What does ''' mean in Python?
Have been told that in Python
'''

is used to indicate the start of a multi-line string.
However I have also been taught that this code also allows for the documentation of functions and modules.
Googling, surprisingly, doesn't give a clear answer on what ''' definitively refers to.
So how should I remember, as a beginner, what this Python code refers to?
A multi-line string? An operator to assist documentation? Both? Something else?

Triple quotes ''' (and """) is a marker for a string literal just like quote characters ' and ", which you can see in Python's grammar for String and Bytes literals.
Its only difference to regular quotes is that newlines and unescaped quote characters are allowed within a triple-quoted string literal, which makes triple quotes ideal for documentation in natural language where newlines and unescaped quote characters can appear often.
It is why as a convention triple quotes are used for docstrings, as suggested in PEP-257, although you can still use regular quotes for docstrings.

It is a multiline string.
If the first line of code inside a function or module happens to be a string that is not set to any variable, it is turned into the documentation of the function by setting the __doc__ attribute, and removing the common indentation inside the string.

Thanks. Your answer added to my, now clearer, understanding.
